# upload retrieve image angularjs mvc

Tags: angularjs, image, model-view-controller, upload

Hello evry one I want to upload images to employees and retrive , the way this is code I hope that you help me thanks The article of this example [there](http://www.advancesharp.com/blog/1185/angularjs-crud-with-web-api-entity-framework-bootstrap-modal-popup-part-1) 
or [Download it from there and try](https://github.com/AliAdravi/Advancesharp).

my app.js

```js
var app = angular.module('MyApp', [
    'ui.router',
    'ui.bootstrap',
    'ngAnimate',
    'angularFileUpload',
]);

app.config(['$urlRouterProvider', '$stateProvider', function ($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider) {

    // default route
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

    $stateProvider
        .state('home', {
            url: '/',
            templateUrl: 'app/home/home.html',
            controller: 'homeCtrl'
        })
        .state('about', {
            url: '/about',
            templateUrl: 'app/about/about.html',
            controller: 'aboutCtrl'
        })
        .state('contact', {
            url: '/contact',
            templateUrl: 'app/contact/contact.html',
            controller: 'contactCtrl'
        })
        .state('customer', {
            url: '/customer',
            templateUrl: 'app/customer/customer.html',
            controller: 'customerCtrl'
        })
        .state('customer.detail', {
            url: '^/customer/detail/{customerId:[0-9]{1,5}}',
            templateUrl: 'app/customer/customerdetail.html',
            controller: 'customerCtrl'
        })
        .state('customer.detail.contact', {
            url: '^/customer/detail/contact/{customerId:[0-9]{1,5}}',
            templateUrl: 'app/customer/contact.html',
            controller: 'customerContactCtrl'
        })
}]);

app.directive('loading', ['$http', function ($http) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, elm, attrs) {
            scope.isLoading = function () {
                return $http.pendingRequests.length > 0;
            };
            scope.$watch(scope.isLoading, function (v) {
                if (v) {
                    elm.show();
                } else {
                    elm.hide();
                }
            });
        }
    };

}]);

app.directive('fileUpload', function () {
    return {
        scope: true,        //create a new scope
        link: function (scope, el, attrs) {
            el.bind('change', function (event) {
                var files = event.target.files;
                //iterate files since 'multiple' may be specified on the element
                for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                    //emit event upward
                    scope.$emit("fileSelected", { file: files[i] });
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

end service.js

```js
angular.module('MyApp')
       .factory('Customer', ['$q', '$http', function ($q, $http) {

           var baseUrl = 'api/customer/';
           var contactBaseUrl = 'api/Contact/';

           var customerService = {};
           customerService.customers = [];
           customerService.currentCustomer = {};

           // Search Customers
           customerService.search = function (text) {
               var deferred = $q.defer();
               return $http({
                   url: baseUrl + 'search',
                   method: 'GET',
                   params: { 'searchText': text },
                   cache: true
               }).success(function (data) {
                   deferred.resolve(
                       customerService.customers = data);
               }).error(function (error) {
                   deferred.reject(error);
               })
               return deferred.promise;
           }

           // New Customers
           customerService.newCustomer = function () {
               var deferred = $q.defer();
               return $http.get(baseUrl + "new")
                    .success(function (data) {
                        deferred.resolve(customerService.customer = data);
                    })
               .error(function (error) {
                   deferred.reject(error);
               })
               return deferred.promise;
           }

           // Save Customer
           customerService.Save = function (customer, files) {
               var deferred = $q.defer();
               return $http.post(baseUrl + "Save", customer)
                .success(function (data) {
                    deferred.resolve(customerService.customer = data);
                })

               .error(function (error) {
                   deferred.reject(error);
               });
               return deferred.promise;
           }

           // Customers detail by customer id
           customerService.customerDetail = function (id) {
               var deferred = $q.defer();
               return $http.get(baseUrl + "detail/" + id)
                    .success(function (data) {
                        deferred.resolve(
                            customerService.currentCustomer = data);
                    })
               .error(function (error) {
                   deferred.reject(error);
               })
               return deferred.promise;
           }

           // delete Customers
           customerService.delete = function (id) {
               var deferred = $q.defer();
               return $http.post(baseUrl + "delete/" + id)
                    .success(function (data) {
                        deferred.resolve();
                    })
               .error(function (error) {
                   deferred.reject(error);
               })
               return deferred.promise;
           }
                      
           /*       CUSTOMER CONTACTS
            ************************************/
           customerService.customerContacts = function (id) {
               var deferred = $q.defer();
               return $http.get(contactBaseUrl + "ByCustomerId/" + id)
                    .success(function (data) {
                        deferred.resolve(customerService.conntacts = data);
                    }).error(function (error) {
                        deferred.reject(error);
                    })
               return deferred.promise;
           }

           return customerService;
       }]);
```

controller.js

```js
var app = angular.module("MyApp")
app.controller('customerCtrl', ['$scope', '$state', '$stateParams', '$modal', '$log', 'Customer', function ($scope, $state, $stateParams, $modal, $log, Customer) {

    var customerId = $stateParams.customerId;

    $scope.searchText = '';
    $scope.customers = searchCustomers();
    $scope.contacts = [];
    $scope.customer = null;
    $scope.currentCustomer = null;


    $scope.$watch('searchText', function (newVal, oldVal) {
        if (newVal != oldVal) {
            searchCustomers();
        }
    }, true);


    function searchCustomers() {
        Customer.search($scope.searchText)
        .then(function (data) {
            $scope.customers = Customer.customers;
        });
    };

    $scope.customerDetail = function (id) {
        if (!id) return;
        Customer.customerDetail(id)
        .then(function (data) {
            $scope.currentCustomer = Customer.currentCustomer;
            $state.go('customer.detail', { 'customerId': id });
        });
    };

    /* Need to call after defining the function
       It will be called on page refresh        */
    $scope.currentCustomer = $scope.customerDetail(customerId);

    // Delete a customer and hide the row
    $scope.deleteCustomer = function ($event, id) {
        var ans = confirm('Are you sure to delete it?');
        if (ans) {
            Customer.delete(id)
            .then(function () {
                var element = $event.currentTarget;
                $(element).closest('div[class^="col-lg-12"]').hide();
            })
        }
    };


  



    // Add Customer
    $scope.addCustomer = function () {
        Customer.newCustomer()
        .then(function (data) {
            $scope.customer = Customer.customer;
            $scope.open('sm');
        });
    }

    // Edit Customer
    $scope.editCustomer = function () {
        $scope.customer = $scope.currentCustomer;
        $scope.open('lg');
    }

    // Open model to add edit customer
    $scope.open = function (size) {
        var modalInstance = $modal.open({
            animation: false,
            backdrop: 'static',
            templateUrl: 'app/customer/AddEditCustomer.html',
            controller: 'customerModalCtrl',
            size: size,
            resolve: {
                customer: function () {
                    return $scope.customer;
                }
            }
        });
        modalInstance.result.then(function (response) {
            $scope.currentCustomer = response;
            $state.go('customer.detail', { 'customerId': response.CustomerId });
        }, function () {
            $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
        });
    };



}]);

app.controller('customerModalCtrl', ['$scope', '$modalInstance', 'Customer', 'customer', function ($scope, $modalInstance, Customer, customer) {

    $scope.customer = customer;

    if (customer.CustomerId > 0)
        $scope.headerTitle = 'Edit Customer';
    else
        $scope.headerTitle = 'Add Customer';

    $scope.save = function () {
        Customer.Save($scope.customer).then(function (response) {
            $modalInstance.close(response.data);
        })
    };

    $scope.cancel = function () {
        $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    };

}]);
```

end this is my html template

```html
<div class="form-horizontal">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Employees</legend>

        <div class="col-lg-3">
            <img ng-src="{{currentCustomer.Image ? currentCustomer.Image : 'customerimages/default-image.png'}}"
                 class="img-circle"
                 alt='customer image' />
            <input type="file" name="file" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().uploadFile(this)" id="photo-upload" />
        </div>
       

        <div class="col-lg-8">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputEmail" class="col-lg-3 control-label">Full Name</label>
                <div class="col-lg-8">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="currentCustomer.FullName" disabled>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-1">                    
               n ng-click="editCustomer()"
                            ng-hide="currentCustomer == null"
                            class="btn btn-primary">
                        Edit
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputEmail" class="col-lg-3 control-label">Adress</label>
                <div class="col-lg-8">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="currentCustomer.Address" disabled>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputEmail" class="col-lg-3 control-label">City</label>
                <div class="col-lg-8">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="currentCustomer.City" disabled>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputEmail" class="col-lg-3 control-label">البلد</label>
                <div class="col-lg-8">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="currentCustomer.Country" disabled>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputEmail" class="col-lg-3 control-label">Zip Code</label>
                <div class="col-lg-8">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="currentCustomer.ZipCode" disabled>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-3">
                    <a ui-sref="customer.detail.contact({contactCustomerId: currentCustomer.CustomerId})">Detail</a>
                </div>
            </div>            
        </div>

    </fieldset>
</div>

<div ui-view></div>
```

end this is my Action Save Api Controller

```js
 [Route("api/Customer/Save")]
        [HttpPost]
        public Customer SaveCustomer(Customer customer)
        {
           
            if (customer.CustomerId > 0)
            {
                var dbCustomer = db.Customers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.CustomerId == customer.CustomerId);
                dbCustomer.FullName = customer.FullName;
                dbCustomer.Address = customer.Address;
                dbCustomer.City = customer.City;
                dbCustomer.Country = customer.Country;
                dbCustomer.ZipCode = customer.ZipCode;
                dbCustomer.Image = customer.Image;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return dbCustomer;
            }
            else
            {
                db.Customers.Add(customer);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return customer;
            }
        }
```